# I have two graphs in a single plot and i want one of them to be dashed

Tags: plotting

I have two graphs of the same function with 2 different values for Ec in a single plot and i want one of them to be dashed.
I want the center plot which is centered at 0 to be dashed and gray

[image: plot]

```
Ep = 1;
Ec = {3, 0 };
\[Gamma]21 = 1;
\[Gamma]31 = 0.0001;
\[CapitalDelta]c = 0;
x = 1/2;
\[Rho]21 = 
  Ep/(-I \[Gamma]21 - \[CapitalDelta]p + (Ec^2 Sin[\[Pi] x]^2)/(
   I \[Gamma]31 - \[CapitalDelta]c + \[CapitalDelta]p));
h2 = Plot[Im[\[Rho]21], {\[CapitalDelta]p, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Gray, Dashed}}]
```

Comment: Currently you're multiplying two options together! options are only specified once: here you want `PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Gray, Dashed}}`. the $n$th element of the list is the specification of the style of the $n$th curve

Comment: Post the code instead of picture is necessary in this forum.

Comment: Change the first argument of `Plot` to `Evaluate@Im[\[Rho]21]` and use `PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Gray, Dashed}}`.  Does that produce what you want?